# how can i make this spam ping (for educational purposes)

Tags: python, discord, bots

the problem im having is its only pinging once

```py
import discord
from discord import app_commands
from discord.ext import commands
import os
import random
import turtle

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='#', intents= discord.Intents.all())


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
  try:
    synced = await bot.tree.sync()
    print(f"synced{len(synced)} command(s)")
  except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    
@bot.tree.command(name="spamping",description="Spam Ping A MEMBER")


async def spamping(interaction: discord.Interaction, person_to_ping: str,how_many_pings: int, ghost_true_or_false: bool, message_to_spam: str):



  for i in range(how_many_pings):
     await interaction.response.send_message(person_to_ping+message_to_spam)
bot.run(os.getenv('Token_Key'))
```

im not really sure what to try i feel like interaction is the issue though